# Script flushall - how?

Tags: redis

I have

- a jenkins server
- two AWS ElastiCache Redis instances

Occasionally the developer team needs to issue FLUSHALL, and desires to do so from Jenkins so they don't need to hunt down a system administrator, or fool around in shell.

Optimally, I'd use AWS CLI. I don't see how in the AWS CLI toolset to do this.

Is there a way to execute FLUSHALL from a shell script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at using lamda for AWS environment. This can be a starting point https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-ec.html